# Could this question about Joffrey from Game of Thrones be salvaged?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I wonder why [this question about King Joffrey](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35749/is-king-joffrey-not-actually-roberts-son) was closed.

Of course the **question in the title** has an *obvious* answer, which can be answered by merely making the effort of watching the first few chapters of the TV show. I'm annoyed by the lack of effort in this question, but my annoyance is not reason enough to close it. I'd downvote it instead -- which I actually did.

So was it closed because the title and the actual question do not match? (The title seems to ask about who Joffrey's parents are, but the question ponders whether his true parentage is the source of his alleged madness).

I think one of the two questions *is* constructive, if a bit obvious. Can the question be salvaged by actually asking what's in the title, or going the other way and asking about Joffrey's madness? Is it worth editing it, or should we wait for the original asker to do it?

Comment: I haven't touched the question and don't know a thing about _Game of Thrones_, but the question gives the impression the OP wants a discussion, rather than an answer (and the final line, "How could anyone know?" seems to be asking for [WildMassGuessing](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WildMassGuessing))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could probably be salvaged, but there's really no point if you wanted to salvage the question in the title. Anybody who has read the books (or, I'd assume, seen the show) already knows the answer to that question, or at least should if they paid even the slightest bit of attention. It's a prime candidate for closure, and probably deletion, because it has absolutely zero value.

The other question - Was Joffrey's madness caused by being the product of incest? - is more interesting, and I'd say actually answerable without having to rely on wild speculation given certain topics raised in the source material. I'd be supportive of a rewrite of the question to focus it much more towards that particular topic.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer. I thought some more about a rewrite, and decided it's not my place to do it. It's not a question _I_ would ask, so I leave it to others to either rewrite or ask a new question about it. Case closed!

Comment: Anthony matches my opinion.  In its original state, it's not clear what question is being asked.  Is it the one in the title?  The ones in the body?  Until it gets edited to have 1 clear purpose, it's hard to properly answer.

Answer (score 4):

I voted to close precisely because of the obviousness.  Now, there are different levels of obviousness, but this one is akin to watching the original Star Wars trilogy and then asking if Vader is Luke's father.  Or reading Lord of the Rings and then asking if Aragorn is the King of Gondor.  It's not just an obvious answer, but it's also a major plot point that is shoved right in your face to such an extent that the only way anyone could miss it is by not paying any attention *at all* to the source material.

In other words it's not just *a bit* obvious - it is far far more than that.

Comment: Oh, I agree with you. I was merely being polite. It is _irritatingly_ obvious. But the question is, are obviousness and lack of effort a _close_ reason? Don't downvotes deal with that? To me closing means "it doesn't belong here", while downvotes mean "I don't like this question, or I think it's poorly researched". Maybe I'm wrong :)

Comment: I vote for close reason because it means that bad questions are more likely to move off the front page.

Comment: I agree with this. While the general reference criteria was closed, it still applies to this kind of thing. I tend to think if I'm going to remember the detail a year later easily, it might be general reference... This is well put.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Wouldn't "Too Localized" also apply, then?  "This is so obvious, it'll only apply to the asker" is something that was considered in one of the Gen. Ref. Meta questions

Comment: @Izkata: That would certainly work.